# Как читать ods-документ с помощью конструкции with document.sheets[-1] as table?

Tags: python, open-office

Использую самописный скрипт для выгрузки данных из legacy-продуктачерез ods-документы.

Текущая реализация:

```
import ezodf
from . import db

ezodf.config.set_table_expand_strategy('all')
current_spreadsheet = ezodf.opendoc(filename='./table1.ods')
current_table = current_spreadsheet.sheets[-1]
for row_num in range(current_table.nrows()):
    db.session.add(
        Model_1(
            id=current_table['a%s' % row_num].value,
            name=current_table['b%s' % row_num].value
            )
    )

db.session.commit()
```

Так, как таблиц весьма приличное количество и они имеют разную структуру хотелось бы причесать код вот так:

```
with ezodf.opendoc(filename='./table1.ods') as spreadsheet:
    with spreadsheet.sheets[-1] as table:
        for row_num in range(table.nrows()):
            db.session.add(
                Model_1(
                    id=table['a%s' % row_num].value,
                    name=table['b%s' % row_num].value
                 )
            )
```

Но при выполнении второго варианта получаю следующее:

```
File "uploader.py", line 36, in <module>
    with ezodf.opendoc(filename='./table_1.ods') as spreadsheet:
AttributeError: __exit__
```

Как обойти/отловить данную ошибку?

```
ezodf - 0.3.2
lxml - 3.7.2
python - 3.5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Согласно [PEP-0343](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/) конструкция `with ...` ожидает объект, в котором реализованы методы: `__enter__()` и `__exit__()`:

> In this PEP, context managers provide `__enter__()` and `__exit__()`
>   methods that are invoked on entry to and exit from the body of the
>   with statement.

У объекта возвращаемого `ezodf.opendoc(...)` метод `__exit__()` не реализован, поэтому `with ...` воспользоваться не получится. Можно конечно попробовать написать свой класс унаследовав его от классов `ezodf`, но это по-моему перебор...

У этого объекта даже нет метода `.close()`, поэтому если вы не изменяете документы, то можно просто использовать одну и ту же переменную для разных документов. Если изменяете, то не забывайте сохранять изменения при помощи `.save(...)` или `.saveas(...)`

Можно оформить обработку документов в виде функции.

Пример:

```
def process_sheet(filename, sheet_no=-1):
    sheet = ezodf.opendoc(filename=filename)
    tab = sheet.sheets[sheet_no]
    for row in tab.rows():
        # process data here
        for cell in row:
            print(cell.value, end='\t')
        print()
```

Тест:

```
x       y       z
10.0    20.0    30.0
40.0    50.0    60.0
```

Comment: Спасибо, ушёл читать PEP-0343 и искать другие библиотеки для чтения ods, которыми можно будет лаконично описать ~20 моделей.

Comment: @Tihon, https://github.com/pyexcel/pyexcel-ods3